# How to fix the space between each x ticks in a pgfplot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to plot some data using pgfplot. Here is what I got for now:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xlabel=X,
  xmin = 0,
  xtick = {1,2,3,4,8},
  ylabel=Y,
  enlargelimits=false
]

\addplot coordinates {
  (1,   2000)
  (2,   5000)
  (3,   8000)
  (4,   11000)
  (8,   13000)
};
\addlegendentry{A}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The display is OK, but I do not want to have more space between 4 and 8 than between 1 and 2. I want the same space between each x tick.

Is that possible ?

Comment: What is the meaning of your x-coordinates, if it is not the position? (you can use `1,2,3,4,5` instead of `1,2,3,4,8` !?)

Comment: In my case, it's a number of threads. It has an important meaning

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could change the `xtick` and `xticklabels` as follows

```
  xtick = {1,2,3,4,5},
  xticklabels = {1,2,3,4,8},
```

which gives

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xlabel=X,
  xmin = 0,
  xtick = {1,2,3,4,5},
  xticklabels = {1,2,3,4,8},
  ylabel=Y,
  enlargelimits=false
]

\addplot coordinates {
  (1,   2000)
  (2,   5000)
  (3,   8000)
  (4,   11000)
  (5,   13000)
};
\addlegendentry{A}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh god... That's was too easy. Thanks a lot :)